# Gwt using JSNI to manipulate window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

What I am want to do is really simple.  I have an gwt app with just one button, everytime I click the button, I want my `window.location.hash` changed.

here is what I have so far

```
private native void setLocationHash() /*-{
   var hash = window.location.hash;
   window.location.hash = hash+1;
}-*/;
```

So every time my button click event fires, that JSNI function would be called.
Suppose before button click, my url is
http://127.0.0.1:8888/GwtSampleApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9996#1
after clicking the button, my url SHALL be
http://127.0.0.1:8888/GwtSampleApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9996#2

But so far, this is not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use JSNI as GWT has the History class for your purpose.

```
History.newItem("you_hash_here");
```

see [Documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html)

Comment: String newUrl = Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().setHash("newHash").buildString();
Window.Location.replace(newUrl); This way I don't alter the "back" button behavior